# implement underscore _.every()

Tags: javascript

I have a question about implementing _.every().

My code is here

```
  _.every = function(collection, iterator) {

    if (collection.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return _.reduce(collection, function(accum, item){
      if(!iterator(item)){
        return false;
      } else if((iterator(item))){
        return accum;
      }

    },true);

  };
```

However, accorting to the Underbar Test Suite, my code doesn't work with the statement "should work when no callback is provided"

```
expect(_.every([true, true, true])).to.be.true;

   expect(_.every([true, true, false])).to.be.false;

expect(_.every([false, false, false])).to.be.false;
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Please, let me know hot to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

See what happens if you do not pass the `iterator` callback.

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) { // <-- iterator is undefined
  if (collection.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return _.reduce(collection, function(accum, item){
    if(!iterator(item)){           // <-- undefined is not a function! This will throw an error!
      return false;
    } else if((iterator(item))){
      return accum;
    }
  },true);
};
```

---

In order to fix this, you'd need to check if `iterator` is defined and then call it. Otherwise do some other tests based on your collection items.

Alternatively, you can provide the default value for iterator. This solution might be simpler:

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) { // <-- iterator is undefined
  if (collection.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  // overwrite iterator if it's falsy (in your case it's undefined)
  iterator = iterator || function(item) {
    return item;
  };

  return _.reduce(collection, function(accum, item){
    if(!iterator(item)){
      return false;
    } else if((iterator(item))){
      return accum;
    }
  },true);
};
```

Comment: Thx for your quick answer!
Could you possible do me a favor?
Since I've learning JS for 5 weeks, your code is quite tough for me to understand at once!

As fas as I understand your correction, as iterator was not defined so my code didn't match the test suite, right? 

If so,  what does this code mean 
ex) how this code beneath works..
"  iterator = iterator || function(item) {
    return item;
  }; "

Comment: I mean I want to know how your code match the Test Suite's statement "should work when no callback is provided" 
For me your code look like default for an empty collection.

Comment: @WonBokLee This particular part of code is a shortcut for the equivalent `if(!iterator) { iterator = function(item) { return item; }; }`

Comment: Looking into it for a while, I got a clue. 
Sorry for disturbing you, but I've got one question more. The way it works is in this case "expect(_.every([true, true, false])).to.be.false;" since there's no iterator, function(item) is being an 'iterator'. Since not every values are true ,it returns false
Is my understanding right?

Comment: @WonBokLee Yes, you're correct. `_.every([item1, item2, ... itemN])` should return `true` if and only if all items of the collection are truthy.